# Does Microsoft Teams have a embedded web browser?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

my bot sends an Action.OpenUrl button. The documentation states "When invoked, show the given url either by launching it in an external web browser or showing within an embedded web browser". The link I always open external web browser. What is an embedded web browser? does ms Teams have a built-in web browser?

Comment: This might be referring to the Teams mobile experience...

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow - maybe, but on android the link opens with a separate tab in google chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teams is an [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) app - [link](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/microsoft-teams), meaning it is a Javascript app running in a web browser (a modified Chromium) in the first place.

Teams v2 will move to Edge WebView, so a different browser. [source](https://dev.to/noseratio/some-thoughts-on-the-new-microsoft-teams-2-0-architecture-webview2-reactjs-1gf1)

Comment: The point is whether I can open a link in Microsoft Times without going to a third-party browser

Comment: @Markjuzefin does Teams have an embedded browser? Yes. Can you open arbitrary webpages in it? Probably not. Those could have nasty security implications. Maybe they meant some [internal deep links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) or [apps](https://github.com/microsoft/DevAppsForTeams)?